Error SSL на PyQt
есть проблема, что при загрузке веб-страницы через движок PyQt6 я получаю в консоль множество ошибок: [14196:5292:0605/144729.706:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Делал интерфейс через Qt Designer весь код автоматически был конвертирован из ui в py, поэтому не понимаю, как мне необходимо внести изменения, чтобы эти ошибки не сыпались в консоль.
Единственная строчка кода, которую я использую в основном коде программы, которая касается веб-движка:
 self.ui.webEmail.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.ru/"))

Помогите пожалуйста, как убрать ошибки

Milk , пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.
